# Convert RAW to PNG with Imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to convrt RAW image to PNG with Imagemagick.
Imagemagick version I'm using is 6.7.8-9.

The RAW image want to convert is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V1c-ytjkLaCM3KbAc6Yxj2nfWzNkYohc/view?usp=sharing

My client gave me a big RAW image which contains more than 1000 RAW images and it is generated from Dicom. Firstly, I cropped just one image with the command (crop command did not work somehow, so used convert):

```
convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 UYVY:original.raw result.raw
```

result.raw appears good on ImageJ.
Now, I have no idea how to get PNG from it.
I tested some commands:

This one generated a very bad quality:

```
convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 gray:result.raw result.png
```

This one gets green-ish image:

```
convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 uyvy:result.raw result.png
```

If I open result.raw on ImageJ and save as PNG, it works perfectly.

Comment: What does a proper result look like? Post a screen snap from ImageJ showing the correct result. Is your raw data signed or unsigned 16-bits?

Comment: Try `convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 uyvy:result.raw -separate +channel result.png` and pick the channel you think is best.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for your reply. Your command generates much better images, however they still look differnt to the original RAW image.
This is one of the PNG generated from your command:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B7PyctpseUP3Jra5YyRzwp1haa7cM_na/view?usp=sharing)
This PNG is created from ImageJ and this is the one I need:
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ihJsW922gAdoeJ-8ai3rLiHK9di7vPn_/view?usp=sharing)
My RAW is signed 16 bits. My client just told me the RAW is 1ch(mono), so should be converted to 3ch(rgb) gray and then convert to PNG. PNG won't be a weird color then.

Comment: I think the issue is that ImageMagick is processing as unsigned 16-bits and your data is signed. I do not know if ImageMagick can handle the signed data. You should ask on the ImageMagick forum whether there is a way to read the signed raw image data.

Comment: Actually, my client said that the RAW should be opened with "16bit signed and little endian" on ImageJ. So, the proper image should look like: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ziTATEAv2IZuXP4-clgLdcBM3Hwi7Xft/view?usp=sharing) Now, the question is how to add "signed" and "little endian". I tried something like `convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 -define png:swap-bytes=on -define signed uyvy:result.raw result.jpg` with no luck.

Comment: Did you consider using real RAW processor like darktable, Or use ufraw?

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from Imagemagick community. Firstly, below code to get the first image from the original raw was wrong.

```
convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 UYVY:original.raw result.raw
```

This is the correct way (512*512*2bytes=524228)

```
head --bytes 524288 original.raw >firstimage.raw
```

Then convert to PNG:

```
magick -size 512x512 -depth 16 gray:firstimage.raw -evaluate AddModulus 50% -auto-level x.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way in ImageMagick that I think is more intuitive to your signed raw data. I simply specify the data is signed using `-define quantum-format=signed`. Then stretch the result to full dynamic range using `-auto-level`.

```
convert -size 512x512 -depth 16 -define quantum:format=signed gray:original.raw -auto-level result.png
```

If using ImageMagick 7, then replace convert with magick.